# Hibernate: MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have a class with the following fields:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "customers")
public class Customer {
    @Id
    int id;
    String name;
    String items;
    String when;
    String where;
    ... // getters and setters
}
```

I've created a table in MySQL database called "customers":
**Columns:**

```
id int(11) PK 
name varchar(45) 
items varchar(45) 
when varchar(45) 
where varchar(45)
```

And I'm trying to add the class into the database like this:

```
Customer customer = new Customer();
customer.setId(1);
customer.setName("Rextuz");
customer.setItems("red_rose1");
customer.setWhen("1_1_2015");
customer.setWhere("len");
... // getting a session factory
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
session.beginTransaction();
session.save(customer);
session.getTransaction().commit();
session.close();
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Hibernate: insert into customers (items, name, when, where, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
дек 14, 2014 12:20:17 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 1064, SQLState: 42000
дек 14, 2014 12:20:17 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'when, where, id) values ('red_rose1', 'Rextuz', '1_1_2015', 'len', 1)' at line 1
```

Are there any ideas how to fix it? Im using org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using SQL keywords `when` and `where` in your `Customer` class, that's why exception came when hibernate fire your query on sql database, if possible you have change the name of `Customer` class properties.

OR

You have to do something like following code.

```
public class Customer {
  .... 
   @Column("TX_WHEN")
    String when;

    @Column("TX_WHERE")
    String where;
    ... // getters and setters
}
```

and you have to change your **customers** table accordingly.

Comment: Thank you so much. I would never guess whats wrong.

Comment: Yes we have to take care about database keywords when we are going to create class.